# How to generate a list of dates on AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, athens

I need to generate a list of dates between two dates start date and end date here I need from 1/1/2022 to the end of the year on AWS Athena without creating table I need only query view
the output should be:

```
|date|
|--|
|1/1/2022 |
|2/1/2022 |
|3/1/2022 |
```

etc to a specific date.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`sequence`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=sequence#id6) function which supports dates and timestamps:

```sql
sequence(
   current_date, -- some start date
   current_date + interval '3' day, -- some end date 
   interval '1' day) -- step
```

And then use `unnest` which will flatten the generated array:

```sql
select t.date
from (select sequence(current_date, current_date + interval '3' day, interval '1' day) dates),
     unnest(dates) as t(date);
```

Output:

| date |
| --- |
| 2022-09-26 |
| 2022-09-27 |
| 2022-09-28 |
| 2022-09-29 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sequence function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) to generate an array with a start date and an end date